# Problem on Flutter flame updating spritecomponent position

Tags: flutter, dart, flame

I am new to flutter flame development, and i am trying to make a object that contain a spritecomponent and sprite animation component, currently i am trying to update there position and i got following code:

```
class BombObject {
  late BombSprite sprite;
  late BombExplosionSprite sprite_animation;
  late Vector2 coordinates;
  BombObject() {
    coordinates = randomCoord();
    sprite = BombSprite(coordinates: coordinates);
    sprite_animation = BombExplosionSprite(coordinates: coordinates);
  }

  Vector2 randomCoord () {
    final random = Random();
    final x = random.nextInt(500);
    final y = random.nextInt(500);

    print("x: $x y:$y");
    return Vector2(x.toDouble(), y.toDouble());
  }

  void init_position() {
    sprite.position = coordinates;
    sprite_animation.position = coordinates;
  }
}

class BombSprite extends SpriteComponent  with HasGameRef<MainGame> {
  Vector2 coordinates;

  BombSprite(
    {
      required this.coordinates,
    }
  );

  @override
  Future<void>? onLoad() async {
    await super.onLoad();

    this.anchor = Anchor.center;

    this.sprite = await gameRef.loadSprite('bomb/bomb.png');

    this.position = coordinates;
  
    this.size = Vector2(100, 100);
  }

}

class BombExplosionSprite extends SpriteAnimationComponent  with HasGameRef<MainGame> {
  late SpriteSheet explosionSpriteSheet;
  Vector2 coordinates;

  BombExplosionSprite(
    {
      required this.coordinates,
    }
  );

  @override
  Future<void>? onLoad() async {
    await super.onLoad();

    this.anchor = Anchor.center;

    final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load("assets/images/bomb/explosion.png");
    final Uint8List bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
    final ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(bytes);
    final ui.FrameInfo frameInfo = await codec.getNextFrame();

    explosionSpriteSheet = SpriteSheet(
      image: frameInfo.image,
      srcSize: Vector2(100, 96),
    );

    this.position = coordinates;

    this.size = Vector2(100, 100);

    this.animation = explosionSpriteSheet.createAnimation(row: 0, stepTime: 0.1);
  }
}
```

And then after i add and render these two components at the onload function of the flame game object, these two object appear to have their position not being updated, the position shown on the screen is wrong, but then when i check the variables value by printing it out, it did got updated. But then why is its actual position wrong? why is it just siting on the top left corner of the screen?

Here is the code how i call it

```
class MainGame extends FlameGame {
  late BombObject bomb1;
  late BombObject bomb2;
  Sprite? sprite;

  MainGame() {
    bomb1 = BombObject();
    bomb2 = BombObject();
  }

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    sprite = await loadSprite('bomb/bomb.png');
    add(bomb1.sprite);
    add(bomb2.sprite_animation);
  }

  @override
  void render(Canvas canvas) {
    super.render(canvas);
    bomb1.sprite.render(canvas);
    bomb2.sprite_animation.render(canvas);
    sprite!.render(canvas, position: Vector2(100, 100));
  }

  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    bomb2.sprite_animation.update(dt);
    print(bomb1.sprite.position);
    print(bomb2.sprite_animation.position);
  }

}
```

For now, just position is not working, size animation and stuff works fine, what did i did wrong here? Can anyone give me some help? (I did try updating sprite.x and sprite.y it got the same result)

Answer (score 0):

You should not call `render` and `update` manually on your components, that is done automatically after you have called `add` on them.

Also, I recommend that you use the `BombSprite` as your base component and then add the `BombExplosionSprite` to that component, since it seems to me like the animation should be following the `BombSprite`, so there is no need to create the outer `BombObject` class like you have.

When you add the explosion component to the `BombSprite` you only have to set the position of the `BombSprite` all the child components will follow.

So something like this:

```dart
class BombSprite extends SpriteComponent  with HasGameRef<MainGame> {
  BombSprite();

  Vector2 randomCoord () {
    final random = Random();
    final x = random.nextInt(500);
    final y = random.nextInt(500);

    print("x: $x y:$y");
    return Vector2(x.toDouble(), y.toDouble());
  }

  @override
  Future<void>? onLoad() async {
    await super.onLoad();

    anchor = Anchor.center;
    sprite = await gameRef.loadSprite('bomb/bomb.png');
    position = randomCoord();
    size = Vector2(100, 100);

    // Note this addition to add a child component:
    add(BombExplosionSprite());
  }
}

class BombExplosionSprite extends SpriteAnimationComponent with HasGameRef<MainGame> {
  @override
  Future<void>? onLoad() async {
    await super.onLoad();

    final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load("assets/images/bomb/explosion.png");
    final Uint8List bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
    final ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(bytes);
    final ui.FrameInfo frameInfo = await codec.getNextFrame();

    final explosionSpriteSheet = SpriteSheet(
      image: frameInfo.image,
      srcSize: Vector2(100, 96),
    );

    size = Vector2(100, 100);
    animation = explosionSpriteSheet.createAnimation(row: 0, stepTime: 0.1);
  }
}
```

And then your game will just look like this:

```dart
class MainGame extends FlameGame {
  late BombObject bomb1;
  late BombObject bomb2;

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    final sprite = await loadSprite('bomb/bomb.png');
    bomb1 = BombObject();
    bomb2 = BombObject();
    add(bomb1);
    add(bomb2);
  }
}
```